# Creating Delegate in UIScrollView Subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I have subclassed a UIScrollView to customize it a bit. I am trying to create a delegate that will notify several other classes that a user has done a certain thing in the UIScrollView. In my UIScrollView class I have the code below. The problem I am running into is I am getting the warning

> Property 'delegate' 'retain (or strong)' attribute does not match the
>   property inherited from 'UIScrollView'

I see that this is because my Class in inheriting from UIScrollView, but my delegate is conforming to the NSObject. This is the first time I tried creating my own delegate. What can I do to fix this?

My Code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ChangeSpaceDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)changeSpace:(int)spaceId;

@end

@interface CustomUIScrollView : UIScrollView {
    id<ChangeSpaceDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic)id delegate;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, you are redefining the property attribute on the `delegate` property you get from `UIScrollView`. It should, like all delegates, be `weak` (or, pre-iOS 5, `unsafe_unretained`).

However, you shouldn't do it this way. `UIScrollView` already has a delegate, and if you expect to put your own delegate object implementing your new delegate methods into it, the inner workings of `UIScrollView` aren't going to be happy. Define a new protocol and a new delegate property for it.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ChangeSpaceDelegate> changeSpaceDelegate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create the `delegate` object in custom scrollview class since you are subclassing it from `UIScrollView`. You can directly use it as `self.delegate` in your custom scrollview class.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Steve Madsen, I often add own delegate properties for subclasses. Like `UITableView` has separate `DataSource` and `Delegate` properties, and being assigned with the same object. In a long run, this will definitely pay off by not forcing you to repeat what have been already implemented in super class, and keeping your subclass implementations more manageable